# How to list all possible string arguments of a specific function?

Tags: programming, options, undocumented

For example, to learn the function `Alphabet`, we can read [its document](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html). But it's rather ambiguous, like "Some languages have extra properties". How to find all the languages that can be used in `Alphabet` ?
And how to find all the extra properties of those languages, like "index characters" of "spanish" `Alphabet["Spanish", "IndexCharacters"]`?

Which means how to find all possible strings that can be passed into `Alphabet[#]&`  ,or  can be passed into `Alphabet["Spanish",#]&` ?

For more examples, how to find all possible strings that can be used in `Entity[#]&` , or in `Entity["PlaneCurve",#]&`, or in `Entity["PlaneCurve","Cardiod",#]&`?.

How to find all possible strings that can be used in `SystemModel["Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic", #]&`?

This question is not specified in those three functions. Is there a more general way to find all those strings which can be used as arguments or options in any functions?

Answer (score 5):

My first attempt involved trying `Alphabet` on every language from `EntityList@"Language"`, all 9211 of them.  I also dug around with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@Alphabet `` and found a few more.

b3m2a1's comment gets most or all of those languages with his one-liner:

```
EntityValue[EntityClass["Alphabet",All],"FullCharacters","Association"]
```

It's hard to compare his code to my results, since the alphabets given don't match with the results of `Alphabet` in every case.  Consider `StringJoin@Alphabet@"Korean"` (no different with the Entity vs "Korean")

```
ㄱㄲㄴㄷㄸㄹㅁㅂㅃㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㅏㅐㅑㅒㅓㅔㅕㅖㅗㅘㅙㅚㅛㅜㅝㅞㅟㅠㅡㅢㅣ
```

vs what is returned by `EntityValue`

```
Entity["Alphabet","Korean::2v535"] -> 
"ㄱᄀ-ᄒ伽佳假價加可...廊朗浪狼來ㅁㅂㅅㅇ樂ㅈㅊ車ㅋㅌㅍㅎ滑ᅡ-ᅵᆨ-ᇂ郎"
```

(I've added the ellipsis and stringjoin)

---

Are you more interested in which language/curve/other entities *exist*, or are you interested in what are all the valid inputs and outputs of functions like `Alphabet`?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: `EntityValue` can be used to extract all property values more efficiently. E.g. ``EntityValue[EntityClass["Alphabet", All], "FullCharacters", "Association"]``

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I'm more interested in all the valid inputs of functions.

Comment: `Alphabet` calls ``System`CharacterFunctionsDump`iAlphabet`` which calls either

**(1)** ``System`CharacterFunctionsDump`iWritingScriptData`` for Entity["WritingScript",\_] inputs,
**(2)** ``System`CharacterFunctionsDump`iAlphabetScriptData`` for String inputs, or **(3)** ``System`CharacterFunctionsDump`getLanguageAlphabet`` for Entity["Language",\_] inputs.

The first two are hardcoded.  The last one looks up Entity properties.  This is it; there is an explicit `Except@Alternatives[...]` definition which throws an error if it's not a String or appropriate Entity.

Comment: I'll add that the precise values of Entities doesn't really matter: at the end of the day these things are in a database because someone put them there, not because they were derived or provably true.